# A liquid ETF that tracks the us dollar

Tags: canada, etf, usd-us-dollar, liquidity

Are there any liquid ETFs that track US dollar. I can only find this one, but this has very low daily volume (~70k shares)
http://www.horizonsetfs.com/pub/en/etfs/?etf=DLR&

Comment: Doesn't a sack full of dollar bills track the dollar exactly?

Comment: @DJClayworth OP is in Canada, and an ETF like DLR is useful for holding USD in accounts that permit only CAD cash holdings.

Comment: @Victor123 I've found DLR to be liquid enough. I'm not aware of any better yet similar ETF that holds just cash and is quoted in both USD and CAD. DLR is very popular with fans of Norbert's Gambit, a way to avoid usurious foreign currency exchange fees charged by many Canadian brokers.